# Publish to gh-pages using yarn in windows doesnt work

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I am trying to publish to gh-pages using yarn on windows 10. 
this is my script:

```
"scripts": {
  "gh-pages":  "gh-pages --dist '.' --src '{index.html,dist/**,CNAME}'"
 }
```

and i have a CNAME file in my root directory. now when i run

```
yarn gh-pages
```

I get this error:

> $ gh-pages --dist '.' --src '{index.html,dist/**,CNAME}'
>   ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'F:\Source..\'.''
>   error Command failed with exit code 1.
>   info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Any idea what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

`$` on Windows means a git bash prompt.

And [`yarnpkg/yarn` issue 5717](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5717) mentions:

> `yarn run` doesn't work in Git Bash due to strange path modification.
>
> The only workaround I found was downgrading to 1.5.1, Yarn was unusable with this bug, unfortunately.

So check your yarn version, .yarnrc content, and your %PATH% (from CMD): it is best to test that with the simplest PATH possible to avoid any side-effect from other installed program paths.